# Fullpage.js + Affix.js

Tags: fullpage.js

Boas, estou tendo dificuldade em fazer funcionar 2 plugins em harmonia.
O fullpage e o affix.

Segue exemplos abaixo de como esta e como eu queria que ficasse.

[image: Isso é a home com o menu transparente]

[image: Essa é a segunda section tbm com menu transparente]

[image: Isso é como deveria ficar e como eu quero que fique.]

1. A primeira imagem: Isso é a home com o menu transparente
2. A segunda imagem: Essa é a segunda section tbm com menu transparente
3. A terceira imagem: Isso é como deveria ficar e como eu quero que fique.

Segue em anexo o cod html e o js que usei.

```js
/* affix the navbar after scroll below header */
$('nav').affix({
      offset: {
  top: $('#section1').height()
      }
});
```

```css
html,body {
 height:100%;
}

.home {
 background-size:cover;
 background-image: url('../img/BG.jpg');
}

.affix {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:padding 0.2s ease-out;  
 -o-transition:padding 0.2s ease-out;         
 transition:padding 0.2s ease-out;
}

.affix a{
 color: #000 !important;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
 .secundary_logo {
  display: none !important;
 }
 .affix .secundary_logo {
  display: block !important;
 }
 .affix .first_logo {
  display: none !important;
 }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
 .affix-top {
  /* navbar style at top */
  background-color:transparent;
  color: #1a1a21;
  border-color:transparent;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease; 
  -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;         
  transition:all 0.5s ease;  
    }
 .secundary_logo {
  display: none;
 }
 .affix .secundary_logo {
  display: block;
 }
 .affix .first_logo {
  display: none;
 }
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-link,
nav .navbar-brand {
 color: #fff;
 
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.quemsomos{
 background-color: #000 !important;
}

.nav-redes{
 border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}

.affix .nav-redes{
 border-left: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://v40.pingendo.com/assets/4.0.0/default/theme.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/javascript.fullPage.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" type="text/css"></head>

<body>



<nav id="nav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md d-block d-sm-block d-md-none" data-spy="affix">
 <div class="container">
  
 <a class="first_logo " href="#"><img height="84" alt="LEPHI" src="img\logo-1.png"></a>
  
 <a class="secundary_logo" href="#"><img height="84" alt="LEPHI" src="img\logo-2.png"></a>
  
 <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">QUEM SOMOS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVIÇOS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">PROJETOS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTATO</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<nav id="nav1" style="padding: 0; !important" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md d-none d-sm-none d-md-block" data-spy="affix">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center justify-content-center">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage" class="nav-item mx-1">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#firstPage">QUEM SOMOS</a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage" class="nav-item mx-1">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#secondPage">SERVIÇOS</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <ul class="navbar-nav mx-4">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"  class="nav-item">
     <a class="first_logo" href="#firstPage"><img height="80" alt="LEPHI" src="img\logo-1.png"></a>
     <a class="secundary_logo" href="#firstPage"><img height="80" alt="LEPHI" src="img\logo-2.png"></a>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li data-menuanchor="4rdPage" class="nav-item mx-1">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#3rdPage">PROJETOS</a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="5rdPage" class="nav-item mx-1">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#4rdPage">CONTATO</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   
   <ul class="navbar-nav py-4 ml-2 nav-redes">
    <li class="nav-item ml-3">
     <a class="first_logo" href="#"><img height="22" alt="LEPHI" src="img\facebook-1.png"></a>
     <a class="secundary_logo" href="#"><img height="22" alt="LEPHI" src="img\facebook-2.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item mx-3">
     <a class="first_logo" href="#"><img height="22" alt="LEPHI" src="img\instagram-1.png"></a>
     <a class="secundary_logo" href="#"><img height="22" alt="LEPHI" src="img\instagram-2.png"></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
 
<div id="fullpage">
 
 <div class="section" id="section0">
 <section class="home">
 <div class="py-5 text-center">
  <div class="container py-5">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <h1 class="display-3 mb-4 text-primary">Hero image intro</h1>
     <p class="lead mb-5">Pingendo is a HTML editor for everyone. Easy for newbies, useful for professionals.
     <br>Code quality is a must. Pingendo generates clean, battle-tested, modular Bootstrap 4 code. </p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg mx-1 btn-secondary">A claim here</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mx-1">Your call to action</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </section>
 </div>
 
 <div class="section" id="section1">
 <section class="quemsomos" id="quemsomos">
 <div class="py-5 text-center">
  <div class="container py-5">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <h1 class="display-3 mb-4 text-primary">Hero image intro</h1>
     <p class="lead mb-5">Pingendo is a HTML editor for everyone. Easy for newbies, useful for professionals.
     <br>Code quality is a must. Pingendo generates clean, battle-tested, modular Bootstrap 4 code. </p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg mx-1 btn-secondary">A claim here</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mx-1">Your call to action</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </section>
 </div>
 
 <div class="section" id="section2">
 <section id="servicos">
 <div class="py-5 text-center">
  <div class="container py-5">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <h1 class="display-3 mb-4 text-primary">Hero image intro</h1>
     <p class="lead mb-5">Pingendo is a HTML editor for everyone. Easy for newbies, useful for professionals.
     <br>Code quality is a must. Pingendo generates clean, battle-tested, modular Bootstrap 4 code. </p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg mx-1 btn-secondary">A claim here</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mx-1">Your call to action</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </section>
 </div>
 
</div>
 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bassjobsen/affix/master/assets/js/affix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', '5thpage'],
  menu: '#nav1',
  navigation: true,
  navigationPosition: 'right',
  navigationTooltips: ['First page', 'Second page', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'Fifth and last page'],
  easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)',
  responsiveWidth: 1100
 });
});
 
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

- Com fullpage.js - http://estudiolephi.com/lephi2.0/
- Sem fullpage.js - http://estudiolephi.com/lephi/

*Notem a diferença no menu

Comment: Qual é o seu problema afinal? O cor branca no Menu ou a imagem que não está carregando e ficando fullscreen? Pelo layout das imagens nem precisa de JS para fazer essas coisas... Qual é a interferência de um plugin no outro? Qual erro apresenta?

Comment: Não entendi ao certo o problema, por favor descreva o que vc já tentou e o que aconteceu, se possível com os logs do console

Comment: Fiz o upload do site como fullpage e sem o fullpage, vocês irão ter uma ideia do que quero.
http://estudiolephi.com/lephi/
http://estudiolephi.com/lephi2.0/